# building a Wizard using RStudio Addin / Shiny Gadget (seq. dialogueViewer() )

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I would like to build a Wizard for my [R package](http://qua.st/decompr/) using [Shiny Gadgets / RStudio Addins](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/#shiny-gadgets).

Essentially, this should comprise of a series of sequential `dialogueViewer()` windows.

For this I need:

1. a way to pass information from one `dialogueViewer()` to the next.
2. that only the first `dialogueViewer()` appears in the Addins menu / dropdown.

**EDIT:** I started working on something [here](https://github.com/bquast/ShinyGadgetWizard) but I get this error:

```
Error in handlers$add(handler, key, tail) : Key / already in use`
```

Any thoughts?

The second problem is relatively easily solved by only registering one function in the `inst/rstudio/addins.dcf` file.